# symfony 2 No route found for "GET /"

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 returns No route found for "GET /" when I try to run http://localhost/app_dev.php, but this url works: http://localhost/app_dev.php/hello/Symfony. I removed AcmeDemoBundle and I'm trying to run an example bundle from a symfony2 tutorial. What is wrong ?

app/config/routing.yml :

```
ShopMyShopBundle:
resource: "@ShopMyShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

app/config/routing_dev.yml :

```
_assetic:
resource: .
type:     assetic

_wdt:
resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
resource: routing.yml
```

src/Shop/MyShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml :

```
ShopMyShopBundle_homepage:
pattern:  /hello/{name}
defaults: { _controller: ShopMyShopBundle:Main:index }
requirements:
    _method:  GET
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have a route for `/`. Change your definition to this:

```
ShopMyShopBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ShopMyShopBundle:Main:index }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

Answer (score 12):

The above answers are wrong, respectively aren't answering why you're having troubles viewing the demo-content prod-mode.

Here's the correct answer: clear your "prod"-cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env prod
```

Comment: I have the same now, I followed all the suggestions, but nothing worked. I think all answered are outdated.

Comment: Today with annotations we have to remember to activate annoations in the config.yml file of our bundle :
all:
    resource: "@OurBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

Comment: This is now `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: This is now symfony console cache:clear --env=prod

Answer (score 5):

This work for me:

```
cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 3):

Using symfony 2.3 with php 5.5 and using the built in server with

```
app/console server:run
```

which should output something like:

```
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

then go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/app/example

this should give you the default, which you can also find the default route by viewing src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Answer (score 1):

Prefix is the prefix for url routing. If it's equals to '/' it means it will have no prefix. Then you defined a route with pattern "it should start with /hello".

To create a route for '/' you need to add these lines in your src/Shop/MyShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml :

```
ShopMyShopBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ShopMyShopBundle:Main:index }
```

Answer (score 1):

i could have been only one who made this mistake but maybe not so i'll post.

the [format for annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc#DocBlock) in the comments before a route has to start with a slash and **two** asterisks. i was making the mistake of a slash and only one asterisk, which PHPStorm autocompleted.

my route looked like this:

```
/*
 * @Route("/",name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
}
```

when it should have been this

```
/**
 * @Route("/",name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    return $this->render('default/base.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried that error , I got it right by just adding /hello/any name because it is path that there must be an hello/name

example : instead of just putting  http://localhost/app_dev.php

put it like this way  http://localhost/name_of_your_project/web/app_dev.php/hello/ai

it will display Hello Ai . I hope I answer your question.