# No route found for /, even though a route is defined

Tags: php, symfony

I'm getting the following error when I try and visit my **app_dev.php** page:

```
No route found for "GET /"
```

The thing is that I defined this route, my routing.yml file looks like this:

```
 0 v42homepage:
 1     pattern:  /
 2     defaults: { _controller: v42Bundle:Default:index }
 3
 4 v42meetTheTeamPage:
 5     pattern:  /meetTheTeam
 6     defaults: { _controller: v42Bundle:Default:meetTheTeam }
 7
 8 v42whatWeDoPage:
 9     pattern:  /whatWeDo
10     defaults: { _controller: v42Bundle:Default:whatWeDo }
11
12 v42contactUsPage:
13     pattern:  /contactUs
14     defaults: { _controller: v42Bundle:Default:contactUs }
15
16 v42homepage:
17     pattern:  /login
18     defaults: { _controller: v42Bundle:Default:login }
```

And here is my controller:

```
<?php
 47
 46 namespace v42\WebsiteBundle\Controller;
 45
 44 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 43
 42 class DefaultController extends Controller
 41 {
 40     public function indexAction()
 39     {
 38         $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
 37
 36         $response = $templating->renderResponse('v42Bundle:Default:index.html.twig');
 35
 34         return $response;
 33     }
 32
 31     public function meetTheTeamAction()
 30     {
 29         $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
 28
 27         $response = $templating->renderResponse('v42Bundle:Default:meetTheTeam.html.twig');
 26
 25         return $response;
 24     }
 23
 22     public function whatWeDoAction()
 21     {
 20         $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
 19
 18         $response = $templating->renderResponse('v42Bundle:Default:whatWeDo.html.twig');
 17
 16         return $response;
 15     }
 14
 13     public function contactUsAction()
 12     {
 11         $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
 10
  9         $response = $templating->renderResponse('v42Bundle:Default:contactUs.html.twig');
  8
  7         return $response;
  6     }
  5
  4     public function loginAction()
  3     {
  2         $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
  1
  0         $response = $templating->renderResponse('v42Bundle:Default:login.html.twig');
  1
  2         return $response;
  3     }
  4
  5 }
```

All of my other paths work, but visiting app_dev.php without providing a path does not, even though this should resolve to my / path by default. What could cause this?

I have tried clearing my cache with Symfony's console program as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15093968/969613).

Thanks

Comment: quick tip .. use @Template to slim down your controller -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

Comment: @nifr Thanks I will check it out, I'm very very new to this, this is my first outing in Symfony2 haha!

Comment: just use `$this->render()` (or the annotation as suggested by @nifr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was called `pattern` is now called `path` in the routing configuration. 
The old key `pattern` is deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0.

Reference [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6826).

If you use a different routing for the dev enviroment i.e. routing_dev.yml:

<kbd>config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
```

You have to import the production routes in routing_dev.yml

<kbd>routing_dev.yml</kbd>

```
# ... dev routes here ... i.e. _wdt, _profiler

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

Furthermore make sure you dont overwrite the `/` route in routing_dev.yml.

the first matching route-pattern always wins - the routes *before* the import of routing.yml in routing_dev.yml will overwrite.

But ... using the same route-names overwrites the ones declared earlier.

You can check which routes exist in your application with

```
app/console router:debug

app/console router:debug --env=prod
```

---

**problem here**: dublicate route names

```
v42homepage:
    pattern:  /

v42homepage:
    pattern:  /login
```

**solution**

rename the second v42homepage to i.e. v42login to resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting, this is how the default routing.yml file in the basic bundle I installed was laid out however. And I have tried changing pattern to path, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: configs as in my example ? no overwriting of / ? error gone? :)

Comment: Just re-checking everything. My routing_dev is as your example says. Then I have 2 routing files, 1 in my app directory and another in my website bundle. The 1 in my app directory (which is referenced in routing_dev) references the one in my website bundle. The 1 in my website bundle is as posted in the question. All my other routes work, it's just the top / route which has stopped working, about the time I added the others. Bit of a head scratcher!

Comment: added route checking console commands to the answer - maybe helpful :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not seeing my / route when I run the router debug command against the dev or prod environment, but I am seeing the others!

Comment: I had duplicated the route name, my / route had the same name as my /login route, which hid the / route, doh'! Thanks for the help + the pointers, much appreciated! :)

Comment: added the solution to the puzzle to my answer - acceptable now ?