# No route found for "GET /" Symfony on login

Tags: php, symfony

I have been trying to follow this tutorial http://donna-oberes.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/user-login-and-logout-step-by-step-with.html  step by step. When I try to login with a incorrect username & password the code works seems to work... but when I enter the correct one I get this error.

> No route found for "GET /" (from "/app/path/web/app_dev.php/login")

Currently my file structures looks like this.

**routing_dev.yml**

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml



login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: SimpleProfileBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

test_security:
    pattern: /secure_area
    defaults: {_controller: SimpleProfileBundle:Security:dumpString }
```

**security.yml**

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity:
            class: Simple\ProfileBundle\Entity\User
            property: username

firewalls:

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

access_control:
      - { path: ^/secure_area, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony 2 No route found for "GET /"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302270/symfony-2-no-route-found-for-get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message describes the problem here. You do not have a route defined for `/`. When you try to log in with the wrong credentials, you get redirected to the login (for which there *is* a route). But, if you succeed, you get redirected to `/`. You do not yet have a route defined for the root.

You'll have to add a route like:

```
index:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: YourBundle:IndexController:index }
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorted the error, but its not kicking off to the /secure_area once you log in?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can change what it redirects to however. The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#redirecting-after-login) has a section on how to configure the redirection.

Comment: I've had ago at this but still cant get it working? Is it possible to show you on skype? (elmbrent118)

Comment: You should probably put up a new question that shows the problem with redirection you have (include configuration).

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by the redirection after successful login and lack of default controller. Please take a look at the Security component [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html).

As documentation states, you have following option to configure your target after successful login:

```
always_use_default_target_path: false
default_target_path:            /
target_path_parameter:          _target_path
use_referer:                    false
```

Comment: The answer above works but keeps redirecting back to the home page once logged in, as its meant to redirect to the /secure_area? Any ideas?

Comment: @BrentFrench could you please post your updated configuration?

Comment: Is it possible you could add me to skype so i can explain? (elmbrent118)

Answer (score 1):

Add `_welcome` to `app/config/routing_dev.yml`

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```