# Symfony2, login using database, bad credentials error, No database queries were performed

Tags: php, database, security, symfony, authentication

Symfony 2.7

I am following and modifying example-project:
http://sourceforge.net/p/p5chi-xshare/wiki/Home/

I am getting  bad credentials error. I do not understand where is the mistake. I am sitting on this already the second day. I looked through dozen forums, corrected form fields, security.yml. But the error persists.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/acme/demo/secured/login
username: xshare, password: xshare.

I believe the error may be in encoders
If I use:

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

I am getting the error: Bad credentials. 
Symfony profiler shows that “No database queries were performed. “

If I try:

```
encoders:
    Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

I am getting the error: Bad credentials. 
Symfony profiler shows that “No database queries were performed. “

If I try:

```
   encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 10
```

I am getting the error: The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?  Symfony profiler shows that “No database queries were performed. “
Or I am getting the error: No route found for "GET /" (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/acme/demo/secured/login") . Symfony profiler shows that “No database queries were performed. “

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\app\config\security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        xshare_db: 
            entity: { class: XshareUserBundle:User, property: username }         

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:   ^/acme/demo/secured/login$
            security: false
            provider: xshare_db
            #anonymous: ~    
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#avoid-common-pitfalls            

        default:
            pattern: ^/acme/demo/secured
            provider: xshare_db
            form_login:
                check_path: /acme/demo/secured/loginCheck
                login_path: /acme/demo/secured/login
            logout:  
                path: /acme/demo/secured/logout
                target: /acme/demo/secured/login


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] }        

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\app\config\routing.yml

```
logout:
    path: /acme/demo/secured/logout
    defaults: { _controller: Acme:DemoBundle:Secured:logout}

login:
    path: /acme/demo/secured/login
    defaults: { _controller: Acme:DemoBundle:Secured:login}    

login_check:
    path: /acme/demo/secured/loginCheck
    #route-path, acme_demo_secured_logincheck   ANY ANY ANY  /acme/demo/secured/loginCheck  
    defaults: { _controller: Acme:DemoBundle:Secured:loginCheck}
```

..\sym_prog\xshare\src\Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User.php

```
   <?php

    namespace Xshare\UserBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use …

    /**
     * Xshare\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="user", indexes = {@ORM\Index(name="search_idx", columns={"firstname", "lastname", "created_at"})})
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Xshare\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="user.email.not_unique")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="user.login.not_unique")
     */
    class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $user_id;

        /**
         * @var string $username
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
         * @Assert\NotBlank(
         *      message="user.not_blank"
         * )
         */
        private $username;

….
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\src\Xshare\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\UserFixtures01.php

```
<?php

namespace Xshare\UserBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use ...

/**
 * Description of UserFixtures
 */
class UserFixtures01 extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //simple user
        $user1 = new User();
        $user1->setActive(1);
        $user1->setBirthDate('11/07/1989');
        $user1->setEmail('xshare@xshare.com');
        $user1->setFirstname('xshare');
        $user1->setLastname('xshare');
        $user1->setPassword('xshare');

        $encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('sha512', false, 10);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user1->getPassword(), $user1->getSalt());
        $user1->setPassword($password);        

        $user1->setPhone('079256354');
        $user1->setSex('m');
        $user1->setTypeAccess('user');
        $user1->setUsername('xshare');
        $manager->persist($user1);        
       ….
        $manager->flush();

    }

}

?>
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\src\Acme\DemoBundle\Controller\SecuredController.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use ...
/**
 * @Route("/demo/secured")
 */
class SecuredController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="_demo_login")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        if ($this->get('request')->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $this->get('request')->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

     return $this->render( 'AcmeDemoBundle:Secured:login.html.twig',
        array('error'         => $error,

         ) );


    }

    /**  
     * @Route("/loginCheck")
     */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    //public function securityCheckAction()
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="_demo_logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction()
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logoutCheck")
     */
    public function logoutCheckAction()
    //public function logoutAction()
    {
        // The security layer will intercept this request
    }
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\src\Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\views\Secured\login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <p>
        Choose between two default users: <em>user/userpass</em> <small>(ROLE_USER)</small> or <em>admin/adminpass</em> <small>(ROLE_ADMIN)</small>
    </p>
    <p> There exists: user: xshare, password: xshare </p>

    {% if error %}
        <div class="error">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path("acme_demo_secured_logincheck") }}" method="post" id="login">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="symfony-button-grey" value="LOGIN" />
    </form>
    {% endblock %}

    {% set code = code(_self) %}
```

Comment: Premising that this tutorial is based on an old Symfony version (with many deprecations), I think it's much better to follow the examples in the Symfony docs for anyone wants to learn symfony starting from 2.7 version (and writing all the code from scratch). If you want to go more deeper you can also take a look at the code of hundreds of updated open source bundles availables on Github.

Comment: Thank you. I will check Github more carefully.   I correct and modify the code. It is according Symfony 2.7 requirements, despite that initial code was older.

Comment: On [knpbundles](http://knpbundles.com/) you will find what you need for almost any type of project (and with the relative links to the Github repository).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is complicated.

1) For the error: No route found for "GET /" , See solution: [No route found for "GET /" Symfony on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972967/no-route-found-for-get-symfony-on-login)
I do not have a route defined for /. When you try to log in with the wrong credentials, i am redirected to the login (for which there is a route). But, if i succeed, you am redirected to / . I have to modify C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\app\config\routing.yml
for instance, remove /general and use / instead
XshareGeneralBundle:
    resource: "@XshareGeneralBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

2) For wrong login credentials, i used share/SecurityBundle, instead of Acme/Demobundle and modified SecurityControler loginAction according vikbert example:
https://github.com/vikbert/starwarsevents
The not working code is commented out.

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.30-0\sym_prog\xshare\src\Xshare\SecurityBundle\Controller\SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace Xshare\SecurityBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Route("/private")
 */
class SecurityController extends Controller {

  /**
   * checks the result of login attempt
   * @Route("/login", name="_login")
   * @Method({"GET","POST"})
   * @Template()
   */
  public function loginAction() {

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ); 
    /*
    if ($this->get('request')->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
      $error = $this->get('request')->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {

      $error = $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    return array(
      'last_username' => $this->get('request')->getSession()->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
      'error' => $error,
      'referer' => $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri(),  
    ); */
  }

  /**
   * @Route("/login_check", name="_security_check")
   */
  public function securityCheckAction() {
    // The security layer will intercept this request
  }

  /**
   * @Route("/logout", name="_logout")
   */
  public function logoutAction() {
    // The security layer will intercept this request
  }
```

...